# What is right-invariance in the context of ranking?

Tags: permutation, ranking

I'm reading a paper called [Unsupervised Rank Aggregation with Domain-Specific Experience](https://www.ijcai.org/Proceedings/09/Papers/186.pdf), and under section 2.1 they talk about the the distance between two permutations of a list. Some examples of this distance metric are the Kendall Tau Distance, and the Spearman Footrule Distance. A property this distance metric could have is right-invariance. In the paper, if a metric has this property it means that it does not depend on how the object is indexed.

This part confuses me, as I don't really understand the difference between an object's rank, and an object's index. If an object is in a ranked list, wouldn't its index directly correlate to its rank? Additionally, they mention that the Kendall Tau Distance is right-invariant, yet it's formula shows that it is dependent on the index of objects i and j. So, what exactly is right-invariance in the context of rank aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects you're ranking arrive to the algorithm in a list, and the rankings you're aggregating arrive to the algorithm as permutations that act on the list. The order of the list/the indices of the objects in the input list is not supposed to matter: the algorithm is supposed to rank the objects in the same way (assign the same *new* indices) no matter the original ordering (ignoring the *original* indices). The new indices correspond to the rank and are important. The old indices (both in the list of objects and in the input rankings) are an artifact of the input representation and care must be taken to make sure they're ignored. Saying that the indices of the objects in the input list doesn't matter is the same as saying that shuffling the input list doesn't change the output of the algorithm. Since the rankings you're aggregating are represented by permutations of the input list, shuffling the input list by some permutation requires you right-multiply all the ranking permutations by the inverse of the shuffling permutation in order to get the same actual rankings of the objects. Since all of these new shuffled ranking permutations still represent the same rankings, the distance metric used to compare the rankings had better be insensitive to the change: such insensitivity is called right-invariance.

As to the right-invariance of the Kendall tau distance: consider the formula `2(x - 3) + 6 - 2x`. This looks like it depends on the number you choose for `x`, but actually it's always zero, so it doesn't actually. Similarly for the Kendall tau: it might not be immediately obvious that it is right invariant (certainly not obvious to me); it's something that you'd probably have to sit down and prove to yourself mathematically. (If they don't even reference a proof, I'd assume it's actually quite trivial if you think about it, but this isn't my field and I'm not going to get it without some pencil and paper.)